# can't change odoo logo in bitnami solution

Tags: odoo, google-compute-engine, bitnami

this is my context:

i have an instance of bitnami's odoo solution running in google cloud plattform. the server run in perfect state.

i've tried to change the company's logo (settings>>company>>logoImage>>click on "pencil icon">> upload the image). And when i finalize the process the logo appear inside the company's form but it doesn't appear in the landpage; also it doesn't appear in the top-left corner (panel).

i've read and tried , every one of the "cache solutions" but still not working, i've probed on firefox and chrome; both respond similary. in firefox's case i had never used before the test access.

so, how can i change the company's logo to showup in the login page?

this is the image in the landing page...
[image]

and this is what i want :
[image]

Comment: what GCP product is it using? https://cloud.google.com/products/

Comment: Do you have acces to the files.

Comment: @DanCornilescu i am using bitnami's odoo VM

Comment: So that would mean Google Compute Engine?

Comment: @CherifOdoo, i can connect to the server via ssh ... i suppose that is what you mean when you talk about "access to the files" no??

Comment: @DanCornilescu yes..

Comment: Alexis, have you been able to solve this issue? I am facing the exact issue on odoo 12.

Answer (score 2):

That logo is a png file located in

```
          addons/web/static/src/discription/logo.png
```

When odoo don't have a cashed logo of your company in the browser he load this logo (odoo logo).  means you need to install a costum module that change the logo or replace that file by your company logo.

sorry i'm using my phone search forr logo file inside web module and replaced or install a costum module that do that if you can.

Comment: And when you test it make sure to clear browser cash

Comment: is fully necesary to use a module? what about transfer a file via ftp using (for example) proftpd? and then restart the instance?